# How to use api forCisco Secure Endpoint (formerly AMP for Endpoints)

Tags: endpoint, cisco

I've been working on utilizing Cisco Secure Endpoint's API to retrieve a list of all devices. I followed the documentation provided, but encountered an issue when attempting to use the API. The error message I received is as follows:

```
{
  "version": null,
  "data": {},
  "errors": [
    {
      "error_code": 401,
      "description": "Unauthorized",
      "details": [
        "Unknown API key or Client ID"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I attempted to make the API call using the following endpoint:
`https://your_client_id:your_api_key@api.amp.cisco.com/v1/computers`

I've tried implementing the Python code provided in the official repository [here](https://github.com/CiscoSecurity/amp-01-basics/tree/master), but I'm encountering the same error.

I've double-checked and confirmed that both the Client ID and API key are valid.

Here's a screenshot of the error message: [erro message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXtlP.png)

I expected this call to successfully retrieve the list of devices registered with the Cisco Secure Endpoint. However, upon making the API call, I encountered the following error message: